# Creating color relief from GeoTIFF using gdaldem returns font name

Tags: gdal, colormap, gdaldem, snodas

I'm trying to generate a color relief map from a SNODAS greyscale geotiff file scaled from 16-bit to 8-bit.  Given the type of data and the scaling, it seems the pixel values are set at 1-5, with 5 being nearest white and 1 being nearest black.  I'm trying to create a color relief from this using `gdaldem` using this:

```
gdaldem color-relief [inputfile.tif] [color.txt] [outputfile.tif]
```

However, I am returned this:

```
ERROR 1: Unknown color : ArialMT;}
```

This appears to be the font used in the text file, rather than the values I've put there, which is this:

```
0 nodata
1 blue
2 yellow
3 orange
4 red
5 white
```

Any ideas here?

Comment: Make sure your text file is plain text and not rich text or something else.  Open it it regular-old notepad to confirm (or `cat` your file or something if you're on *nix).

Comment: That was it.  Simple!  Thank you...